# Update IMG SRC value with the .load() return with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The following puts whatever I echo in **whatever.php** into the **myDiv** div, and it's fine.

```
$('#myDiv').load('whatever.php');
```

If I do

```
document.getElementById(id).src = 'newpic.jpg';
```

If **id** points to a valid IMG, it will replace the picture, and it's fine.

Now, how can I put the output of the load into an IMG SRC?
I tried both, and both are not working:

```
$('#'+id).src.load('whatever.php');
```

or

```
document.getElementById(id).src = $('#hiddenDiv').load('whatever.php');
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the output of `whatever.php` will be just a URL for the img to be replaced ?

Comment: it will be a picture file name in the server, something like ./pics/test.jpg

Comment: You could use `ajax` to get the img name (src) from your server and then on success just replace the src of your img with the new. i am afraid `.load` might not be the best option here to replace an img src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlwaysHelping I realized I didn't need the "load" function, but a simple Ajax call:

```
$.ajax('whatever.php')
  .done(function(data) {
    document.getElementById(id).src = data;
  })
```

I think I have been caught in (ab)using the load function too often, forgetting that a simple Ajax call could represent the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load data and append it to the `<div>` tag first. Then, appending that tag to the body *(some element else)*.

BTW, you can catch event `DOMNodeInserted`. This event is used to catch when some element is inserted to the DOM.

In this example, when the div is ready to use, we add image source inside `<img>` tag.

```js
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#myDiv', function () {
  $('img').prop('src', 'https://www.peta.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/tiger.jpg');
});

setTimeout(function () {
  var div = $('<div id="myDiv">');
  div.append('<img width="100" height="100">');
  
  div.appendTo('body');
},2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events.